# How read Japanese fields from CSV file into java beans?

Tags: java, csv, deserialization, opencsv

I've tried several popular CSV to java deserializers - OpenCSV, JSefa, and Smooks - none correctly read the file:

```
First Name,Last Name
エリック,山中
花子,鈴木
一郎,鈴木
裕子,田中
政治,山村
```

into my java object collection.

OpenCsv code:

```
    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Contact> strat = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Contact>();
    strat.setType(Contact.class);
    strat.setColumnMapping(colNameTranslateMap);
    InputStreamReader fileReader=null;
    CsvToBean<Contact> csv = new CsvToBean<Contact>();
    fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");

    contacts = csv.parse(strat, new CSVReader(fileReader));
```

I've tried setting the Charset to UTF-8, UTF-16 and ISO-8859-1 when I create the FileInputStream, but the collection is never populated properly. As seen in the debugger and System.out the fields contain garbage and often the number of records is wrong.

Comment: How in the world did you specify a charset when creating a `FileInputStream`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) is for reading streams of binary data, like an mp3 or PNG. Instead of a `FIS`, use a [`FileReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) for reading streams of characters.
2. To be blunt: who cares what charsets you tried using if they didn't work? You need to figure out what encoding the CSV file is **actually** using, and set *that* encoding when reading the file. To specify the encoding when using a `FileReader`:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. **To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.**

Comment: FileReader didn't work either. The problem w/ FileReader is it uses the JVM's default charset, you can't set it the way you can w/ FileInputStream.

Comment: Let's see some code. Please edit your question to include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Please read my answer carefully, specifically the bolded part of the quote.

Comment: I'll edit the question but in all cases I am doing exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Thanks `:)` BTW, if you know (or can find out) what the actual encoding of the CSV file is, that will help. A lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4705/discussion-between-matt-ball-and-mebalone)

Comment: When I open a FileReader on the CSV and call getEncoding() it returns UTF8.