# how to read utf-8 chars in opencsv

Tags: java, opencsv

I am trying to read from csv file. The file contains UTF-8 characters. So based on [Parse CSV file containing a Unicode character using OpenCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695699/parse-csv-files-that-contain-unicode-character-using-opencsv) and [How read Japanese fields from CSV file into java beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003333/how-read-japanese-fields-from-csv-file-into-java-beans) I just wrote

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("data.csv"), "UTF-8"), ';');
```

But it does not work. The >>Sí, es nuevo<< text is visible correctly in Notepad, Excel and various other text editing tools, but when I parse the file via opencsv I'm getting >>S�, es nuevo<< ( The í is a special character if you were wondering ;)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure those other editors interpret the file in UTF-8?

Comment: Pretty sure, everything shows the file as unicode.

Comment: Upload your file somewhere and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks aioobe. It turned out the file was not really UTF-8 despite most Win programs showing it as such. Notepad++ was the only one that did not show the file as UTF-8 encoded and after converting the data file the code works.

Answer (score 2):

you can use encoder=UTF-16LE,I'm write a file for Japanese

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for your issue it might helpful to you...

String value = URLEncoder.encode(msg[no], "UTF-8");

thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Use ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-14 or ISO-8859-15 or ISO-8859-10 or ISO-8859-13 or ISO-8859-2 instead of using UTF-8